# Translation of 終わらせる

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm having trouble with the translation of  終わらせている in the following sentence, and as far as I understand it likely translates here as "die". But I never found this meaning for 終わる in vocabulary, and why is it in させる form ?

> 「ええ・・・・・・摩夜さんこそ、犯人が狙う本命だと思うんです」  「いったい・・・・・・誰がそんなことを・・・・・・？」 
>   「それは・・・・・・」  ついさっきまで、詩音さんがやっていると思っていた。 でも彼女は死んでしまった。 
>   だとしたら摩夜さんはもう安全だと思うのだけど・・・・・・  それともーー既に**終わらせている**のだろうか・・・・・・？

Some sort of translation: "Until a moment ago, I though it was Shion-san. But she is dead. In this case I think that Maya-san is safe now...  or - already **dead**."

Comment: I see `死ぬ。` listed as meaning six in [大辞林](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8B), so that meaning *is* listed in dictionaries.

Comment: What seems particularly odd to me is that 終わらせる would be used instead of 終える...I'm looking forward to seeing what the answer to this is.

Comment: According to the context you provided, I think "既に終わらせているのだろうか" is "（犯人は）既に（仕事を）終わらせているのだろうか".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without understanding the whole twisted plot, and I can't really come up with a plausble interpretation.

The reason "dead" is unlikely in this sentence is that 終わる as dead would normally mean committing a suicide as 終える. The subject of this sentence is Maya-san, so this becomes "or Maya might have committed a suicice, and I don't think it flows very well.

Another possibility is "[the killer had achieved his/her objectives and] the killing has ended", which I would say more natural use of 終わらせる, except that this won't explain それとも.

I think it's fair to say this text isn't particularly well written. I think more sentenes that follow might help disambiguate.